# Why do I get cs8604 when building `int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()!);` on macOS, but not on Windows?

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio-code

I have small c# programm for school

```
using System;

namespace Consoleaaa
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int first = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int second = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (first < second)
            {
                for(int i = first; i<=second; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(i);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for(int i = first; i>=second; i--)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

when i start it in vs on windows pc evrything is fine
but when i start it in vs code on mac it gives problem cs8604 in

```
int.parse
```

I tried typing

```
int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()!);
```

but then its just doesnt work

Comment: What does *it just doesn't work* mean exactly?

Comment: `Console.ReadLine()` returns `string?` (string or null), but `int.Parse()` accepts `string` (string, but not null). `string?` and `string` aren't same, so it can't be compiled.

Answer (score 0):

```
    using System;

namespace Consoleaaa
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string? input1 = Console.ReadLine();
            string? input2 = Console.ReadLine();

            if (input1 != null && input2 != null)
            {
                int first = int.Parse(input1);
                int second = int.Parse(input2);

                if (first < second)
                {
                    for (int i = first; i <= second; i++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(i);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int i = first; i >= second; i--)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(i);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid input. Make sure you provide valid integers.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this modified code, I use nullable types for the input1 and input2 variables.